# Appending a DateTime Stamp to end of Filename

Tags: vb.net

All I need assistance on appending a time stamp to the end of each file.

Basically here is the format I need it to be in:

"Number_Doctype_Id_Variable_Name_Currentdatetime"

This is part of the function that builds the name:

```
    Dim strFileName As New StringBuilder
    strFileName.Append(Lab & "_" & dtRecords.Rows(0)(0).ToString)
    Dim strIndex0 As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(2).ToString.Trim
    Dim strIndex1 As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(3).ToString.Trim
    Dim strIndex2 As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(4).ToString.Trim
    strFileName.Append("_" & IIf(strIndex0.Trim.Length > 0, strIndex0, ""))
    strFileName.Append("_" & IIf(strIndex1.Trim.Length > 0, strIndex1, ""))
    strFileName.Append("_" & IIf(strIndex2.Trim.Length > 0, strIndex2, ""))
    strFileName.Append("_" & Format(Now(), "MMddyyyyhhmmss"))
```

However, this is an example of the result:

"01_PDF_123456789_987654321_John Doe_05192016"

I am not for sure why it isn't pulling the exact time, which is what I need to make it unique.

This is what I want it to do:

"01_PDF_123456789_987654321_John Doe_05192016093030"

Any assistance?

Thank You,

Comment: Just a quick note, but if you're using a somewhat newer compiler >= 2008. Use `If()` instead of `IIF()` so it doesn't evaluate both true/false parameters. Unless you want it to of course.

Comment: Make sure something else downstream is not trimming it off.  This might be simpler than stringbuilder and IIF: `Return String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}", dr.Field(Of String)(0),
                                dr.Field(Of String)(2),
                                dr.Field(Of String)(3),
                                dr.Field(Of String)(4),
                                DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmssfff"))`  Probably need to modify it for "Lab" and actual datatypes with ToString()

Comment: Agreed on looking at something after the line. That Format statement appears to work just fine (at least in LinqPad).

Comment: For some reason this `String.Format(DateTime.Now(), "MMddyyyyhhmmss").Dump` in LinqPad returns the date/time twice which may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: That's odd behavior. I'm not sure why it returned twice, but changing it to this made it return once. `Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
d.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss").Dump`

Comment: I tested your code and I am able to create a file with the date and time as its name. I can't tell what is causing your issue. In addition to not using the IIF() like the other commentators mentioned, you are also trimming each strIndex twice. Once when assigning the value from the DataTable and again when checking the length in the IIF().

Comment: Why not just use ToShort/LongDateString() and ToShort/LongTimeString()?

Comment: Don't those methods (ToShort/LongDateString) include the slashes and colons? That would not work for a filename.

Comment: I think they do, yet I seem to recall the IO functions replacing illegal characters automatically. Or perhaps I did that, been a while. Either way, that's easy to do with a call (or two) to string.Replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss")
```

I recommend:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

so you have some sort of order for files with the same rest file name.

Answer (score 0):

The link [String Format for DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) list the DateTime formatting nicely, try this function out. The function takes the DataTable and returns the desired file name. The function leverages the String.Format to convert to desired DateTime format.

```
 Function Foo(dtRecords As DataTable)

    Dim Lab As String = "01"
    Dim docType As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(0).ToString

    Dim strIndex0 As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(2).ToString.Trim
    Dim strIndex1 As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(3).ToString.Trim
    Dim strIndex2 As String = dtRecords.Rows(0)(4).ToString.Trim

    Dim val As String = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5:MMddyyyyhhmmss}", Lab, docType, strIndex0, strIndex1, strIndex2, Now())

    Return val

End Function
```

Driver code should look like this (providing just for more clarity). The DataTable created preserves the schema shown in your function. You would see the 2nd column (i.e. index 1 is title as -Unused-)

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("DocType", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("-Unused-", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Variable", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    dt.Rows.Add("PDF", "//", "123456789", "987654321", "Jhon Doe")

    Console.WriteLine(Foo(dt))

End Sub
```

Hope this would help.